# Hibernate: how to use CONCAT and GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

How can I use `CONCAT()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` in HQL queries?

Answer (score 12):

About `concat`: it works exactly the same way as it does in MySQL (it concatenates strings, it is not an aggregate function).

You can add `group_concat` as an sql function to your configuration. This way you assume that the underlaying DB knows this function, and you tie your program to *MySQL*.

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration; 
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StringType;

// ...
myConf.addSqlFunction("group_concat", new StandardSQLFunction("group_concat", new StringType()));
```

You also indicate that the output of the function is a string. Without this when you `group_concat` numeric fields Hibernate will assume the result also to be numeric and crash.

Comment: +1 for mentioning you tie yourself to mysql. group_concat is not available in, say, microsoft sql server. hibernate aims to be sql vendor independent.

Answer (score 1):

subclass the dialect

and

```
registerFunction("group_concat", new StandardSQLFunction("group_concat", Hibernate.STRING));
```

or use [SQLFunctionTemplate](http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/NHibernate.Dialect.Function/SQLFunctionTemplate.html)

Comment: Can u explain this a bit more? where do I need to write this registerFunction?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using createSQLQuery, use addScalar to that column as String.

```
SQLQuery query = sessionObj.createSQLQuery("select group_concat(column1,column2) as mycolumn from some table group by someThing");
query.addScalar("mycolumn ", Hibernate.STRING);
```

Comment: `Hibernate.STRING` has been deprecated since Hibernate version 3.6.X
[Here is the deprecated document](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html), so you have to use `StringType.INSTANCE`.