# How to use group_concat in Hibernate + Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate

How can I use `addSqlFunction()` in spring when I configured hibernate with hibernate.cfg.xml file? Or is there any other way to use group_concat?

Comment: This is explained here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955580/hibernate-how-to-use-concat-and-group-concat][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955580/hibernate-how-to-use-concat-and-group-concat

Answer (score 2):

If you’re using Spring’s HibernateTemplate to integrate with Hibernate, there’s a simple solution to this. Override Spring’s `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and implement the method `postProcessConfiguration`.

The light at the end of the tunnel (config is the object passed to you by the method `postProcessConfiguration`):

```
config.addSqlFunction( “group_concat”, new StandardSQLFunction("group_concat", new StringType());
```