# Sql server query with concat

Tags: java, hibernate

This is hibernate query i want to run it on sql server but concat function is not in sql server what should i do for that.

```
strQuery = "from TempData where englishLex=:englishLex and category =:category and language=:language and login=:login and domain=:domain group by (concat(englishlex,category)) ";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate: how to use CONCAT and GROUP\_CONCAT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955580/hibernate-how-to-use-concat-and-group-concat)

Comment: what DB are you using ?

Comment: Sir i am using sql server 2005.

Comment: Post the SQL statement that you have run on the sql server. What are you trying to accomplish by this "group by (concat(englishlex,category))"?

Comment: strQuery = "from TempData where englishLex=:englishLex and category =:category and language=:language and login=:login and domain=:domain group by (englishlex + category) ";                                       
I tried this but it is giving an error that Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'temptable.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: That is correct ID will be a primary key hence cannot be used in aggregate queries. If you can clarify what you are trying to achieve maybe we can help you out.

Comment: i want to concat these two colum and i need to find distinct value 
.so this query works in my sql but not in sql server 2005 ..what should i do for that.???

Comment: what should i do for that plese tell me ...what changes i need to do

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Concatenating two strings

```
SELECT 'FirstName' + ' ' + 'LastName' AS FullName
```

Method 2: Concatenating two Numbers

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'R' + CAST(2 AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Method 3: Concatenating values of table columns

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName
FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Contact
```