# GROUP_CONCAT Hibernate HQL

Tags: hibernate, group-by, hql

Basically i am trying to write the following query in Hibernate. Please help me to do the same.

SELECT collaboratoruser,GROUP_CONCAT(collaboratorrole SEPARATOR ',') 
    FROM tbl_conceptcollections_collaborator 
    WHERE collectionid = incollectionid
    GROUP BY collaboratoruser;

I cannot use SQL Query and i want to use only HQL. Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4955580/1031945

Comment: Is this solution compatible with HQL. ?

Answer (score 5):

Frank answer is No.

Why so ?

Hibernate supports only common function/syntax used in multiple database's. 
Moreover, There isn't any group_concat function in MySQL Server and probably could be the same for other database as well.

Solution:

You have to execute it as Native SQL Query only.

Answer (score 0):

You can register Group_Concat function in hibernate.
For example
**Create a class First**

```
public class RegisterSqlFunction extends MySQLDialect {

    public RegisterSqlFunction() {
        super();
        registerFunction("group_concat", new StandardSQLFunction("group_concat", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
    }
}
```

**Second Register in hibernate Propeties**

```
properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "com.app.web.config.sql.RegisterSqlFunction");
```

and then you can use it.

Comment: By this solution you can only use this with CriterialBuilder but not with HQL