# How to use group_concat in hibernate criteria?

Tags: sql, hibernate

I wrote a query in mysql using group_concat like

```
SELECT c1,group_concat(c2) FROM table1 where sno in(1,4,8,10) group by c1;
```

and gives my expected result.

Now the same query I want to write using hibernate criteria.

Comment: a bit old, but actually if you usemysql you can do that. You will need to add it to MYSQL dialect. see more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955580/hibernate-how-to-use-concat-and-group-concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is **No**

**Why?**

Hibernate support only common function/syntax used in multiple database. There ain't any `group_concat` function in Microsoft SQL Server and may be in other database as well.

**Solution:**

You have to execute it as Simple SQL Query.

Comment: I have searched many documents and i did not find any solution so at last i used createSQLQuery(query) in hibernate and got my expected result.

Comment: Yeah. You don't have any choice... ;)

Comment: Is this functionality still not supported ? Is there any workaround than using sql queries ?

Comment: This answer is misleading, maybe because it is outdated. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955580/hibernate-how-to-use-concat-and-group-concat

Answer (score 7):

You have two options (depending on your hibernate version).

**Override the dialect class** 
*any hibernate version*

You will need to subclass your dialect to add `group_concat()`

1. Introduce the dialect override class

Create the following class somewhere in your app (e.g. util package)

```
package com.myapp.util;

import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class MySQLCustomDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {
    public MySQLCustomDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("group_concat", 
            new StandardSQLFunction("group_concat", 
                StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
    }
}
```

2. Map the dialect override class to boot properties

Add the following property to your application.properities

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = com.myapp.util.MySQLCustomDialect`

**Use JPA Metadata Builder Contributor**
*hibernate 5.2.18 or newer only*

1. Introduce metadata builder class

Create the following class, remember to add package & resolve imports.

```
public class SqlFunctions implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

@Override
public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) { 
    metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction( "group_concat", 
        new StandardSQLFunction( "group_concat", 
            StandardBasicTypes.STRING ) ); }
}
```

2. Map new class in application boot properties

> Leave the dialect properties as is

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor = com.myapp.util.SqlFunctions
```

Comment: followed Option 1 and works like a charm, guess that should be the accepted answer right now

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following code snippets

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(table1.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.in("sno",snoarray));
criteria.setProjection("c1");
criteria.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("c1"));
```

Comment: how this criteria object came. I think it is cr as you created and in this case criteria.setProjection("c1"); i think it is wrong(we have to give Projection like cr.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("c1"))); Even in this case also if i add Projections.groupProperty("c1"); it will give only one record as a group not multiple.So i need multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i go through like below code and got expected result

String query="select c1,group_concat(c2) from table1 where sno in (:pageIds)  group by c1";

SQLQuery sqlQuery=   session.createSQLQuery(query);

sqlQuery.setParameterList("pageIds", myList);

List list=  sqlQuery.list();

### c1        group_concat(c2)

aaa       valu1,value2
bbb       value3
ccc       value4,value5,value6