# Registering a SQL function through Entity ManagerFactory

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In Hibernate, I can register **custom SQL fuctions** through the Configuration object:

```
public void registerExtensions(Configuration config) {
    config.addSqlFunction("s_sum", new StandardSQLFunction("sum"));
    ...
}
```

I wish to switch this configuration from "legacy" Hibernate to JPA.

I've read I can register SQL functions by specializing the dialect there : 
[Registering a SQL function with JPA/Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346845/registering-a-sql-function-with-jpa-hibernate) This is *not* what I would like to do.

Is there a way to register these functions when building the Entity Manager Factory ?

I'm running Hibernate 4.3 in a Spring 4.1 context.

Comment: Well you can't because JPA has no such mechanism. You will always be tying your code to one implementation in insisting on such things.

Answer (score 1):

JPA registers SQL through the `@NamedQueries` and `@NamedQuery` annotations. These are placed in the same class as the Entity. See the Javadoc: [Annotation Type NamedQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html).

```
@NamedQuery(
    name="findAllCustomersWithName",
    query="SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.name LIKE :custName"
)
```

and

```
@PersistenceContext
public EntityManager em;
...
customers = em.createNamedQuery("findAllCustomersWithName")
    .setParameter("custName", "Smith")
    .getResultList();
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not what I need. The goal is to extend hql with new functions such as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955580/hibernate-how-to-use-concat-and-group-concat

Comment: Well, the original post you linked to said to extend the dialect class. Did you try that? Id be interested to know the example and/or use case.

Comment: I would like to avoid extending the dialects because my app can run against several RDBMS. I would have to extend several dialects with mostly the same code.

Comment: I suppose you could get the Hibernate Session Factory and use that?

Answer (score 0):

Since Hibernate ORM 5.2.18 and 5.3.1, the best way to register a SQL function when using JPA is to supply a [`MetadataBuilderContributor`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sql-function-jpql-criteria-api-query/) like this:

```
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor 
        implements MetadataBuilderContributor {
         
    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
            "group_concat",
            new StandardSQLFunction(
                "group_concat", 
                StandardBasicTypes.STRING
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Which you can pass to Hibernate via the `hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor configuration property`:

```
<property>
    name="hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor" 
    value="com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.query.function.SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor"
</property>
```

> You might read articles telling you to register the SQL function by extending the Hibernate `Dialect`, but that's a naive solution. For more details about why you should avoid extending the `Dialect`, read [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sql-function-jpql-criteria-api-query/).